# Microsoft Graph API daemon - Error: ResourceNotFound Message: Resource could not be discovered

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to create a daemon using Microsoft Graph API v1.0.
I've registered my app with application permission Calendars.ReadWrite and User.Read.All with granted admin consent.
I get the access token correctly and I call GetUserId that returns the user id for setting requestURI.
After that I want to retrieve Outlook Calendar:

```
var id = await GetUserId(result.AccessToken);

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

String requestURI = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/calendars";

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestURI);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

but I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5ecd547b-9281-4824-94e5-095691e759aa",
      "date": "2020-01-14T16:44:16"
    }
  }
}
```

When I set `requestURI` to `users/{id}` or `organization` the request works fine, but adding `/calendars`, `/events`, or `/mailFolder` results in the above error.

I think my problem is that I used a Personal Account. Do I need to use a Work or School Account? Is it possible to use a Personal Account? Is there another reason for my error?

Update: Code for retrieving a token:

```
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(ClientId)
    .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token&grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com")
    .Build();
string[] scopesClient =
    new string[] { $"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopesClient).ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalServiceException ex) when(ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
{

}
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the token and what do you mean by "personal account"? According to the logs, this token was issued by an AAD tenant using `User.Read.All` and `Calendar.ReadWrite` Application scopes. If you were using an Outlook.com account, the token would only support Delegated scopes.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for replying. This is the code for obtaining the token<br /> `app =ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId).WithClientSecret(ClientSecret).WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token&grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com").Build();
string[] scopesClient=new string[] { $"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
AuthenticationResult result = null;
try {
    result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopesClient).ExecuteAsync();
}catch (MsalServiceException ex) when(ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011")){}`

Comment: I obtain the above error with an Outlook.com account and an not Outlook.com account both.

Answer (score 0):

You're `Authority` isn't quite right:

1. `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` is a legacy setting and not used for the v2 Endpoint (aka authentication with Scopes rather than Resources).
2. The `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilderhandes` setting the OAuth Grant automatically so specifying `grant_type=client_credentials` is not needed.
3. The Authority should only contain the authentication authority (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/`) and the tenant id. The easiest way to handle this is using the `AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic` enumeration

Your token code should look something like this:

```
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(ClientId)
    .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, TenantId)
    .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
    result = await app
        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalServiceException ex)
{

}
```

Note: You will not be able to use this method with an `@outlook.com` account. Personal Accounts do not support `client_credentials`.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I modified my code as you said but the result is the same. I modify requestURI to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta and I get the error code "MailboxNotEnableForRESTAPI". Is it possible that my problem depending from released token?

Comment: That error indicates that the account you're connecting two either does not have a mailbox licensed/provisioned or its not using Exchange Online. On-prem and Hybrid configurations are not supported.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur How can I tell that my account is on-prem or hybrid configuration? I would like to connect my calendar to another app but the app has ResourceNotFound issue:(

Answer (score 0):

In order to call /{user-id}/events,/calendar or /mailFolder to work the user must have mailbox on Exchange Online if you are using client credentials for Daemon application.

We are generally getting this **{"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource could not be discovered."}}** error for organizational users when license is not assigned to the users or mailbox is not configured for them.

In Microsoft personal Account user does not have a mailbox (which make sense with null value as below), so the call wouldn’t work.

[image]

It seems assigning license to a guest account (Microsoft personal account in this case) is not possible and hence the user account never gets access to the calendar service (part of o365 exchange online). due to which it cannot retrieve the calendar information of personal Outlook account.

Comment: For my calendar it returns mail: null as well. Does that mean that there is nothing I can do to connect my calendar to an app?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was using a corporate account as opposed to a personal one. As this answer suggest I just had to skip using tenant ID: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63697577/444630

Answer (score -1):

[image]The documentation states that you have to add the CalenderRead and CalenderReadWrite both. If not, I would use delegated permission if you are using personal account. I would also go to ms.jwt, where they check your token and tell you what is the permission you have and what do you, need to call calendar endpoints

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ashok Subedi for replying. I add CalendarRead permission with granted admin consent but the error is the same. I also check my token in jwt.ms as you said and it seems ok: in roles array I have got "Calendars.Read", "User.Read.All" and "Calendars.ReadWrite". Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you give me the complete api that is giving you an error.